# React - Pass button-value to the (mui) text-field

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, material-ui, textfield

I've got a component that looks like this: [PIN-Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKHMe.jpg)

What I want: After a button is clicked, the value of the button should appear in the text-field.
The text-field is from the Material-UI-library.

At the moment the input only works with the keyboard.
When I click a button, its value appears in the input, but as soon as I press it or another button, the field is reset, so to speak, and only the new value appears.

This is my code that I got at the moment:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//all other imports for icons, the text-field etc.
//----------------------------------------------
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  withoutLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  textField: {
    width: "250px"
  }
}));

function X1Pin() {
  const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    password: "",
    showPassword: false
  });

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    if (values.password.length < 16 && re.test(event.target.value)) {
      setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    }

    console.log(event.target.value); //values in inputField
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({ ...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword });
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleButtonClick = (prop) => (event) => {
    if (values.password.length < 16 && re.test(event.target.value)) {
      setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    }
  };
    
  return (
    <>
      <div className="buttonTable">
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <div>
            <FormControl
              className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password">
                PIN-Input
              </InputLabel>
              <OutlinedInput
                id="outlined-adornment-password"
                type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                value={values.password}
                onChange={handleChange("password")}
                endAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                      onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                      onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                      edge="end"
                    >
                      {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
                labelWidth={75}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button
                className="btn--pin"
                value="1"
                onClick={handleButtonClick("password")}
              >
                1
              </button>
            </td>
            //all other buttons with the same pattern
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default X1Pin;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution myself. Will certainly not be the best, but it works and so serves its purpose:

```
  ...
  const handleButtonClick = (prop, currentValues) => (event) => {
    if (values.password.length < 16 && re.test(event.target.value)) {
      setValues({ ...values, [prop]: values.password + event.target.value });
    }
  };
  ...
```